# .net mail classes vs SQL sp_send_dbmail

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

We have applications that need to send out email notifications from time to time.  We have been using the .net mail classes but recently we are running into the problem of some virus checkers blocking port 25.  To me the correct solution is to set up the correct exclusion rules to allow our app to keep working.  However, some are afraid that this may become a huge hassle in the future, especially as new organizations come on line, and would prefer to use SQL dbmail instead.  I don't particularly like this choice, I would much rather have the application handle this aspect but I'm not sure if it's worth the fight.  Are there any real advantages of using .net mail over the SQL mail?

Comment: wouldnt you also have to open port 25 is you use the database? I wuold say it's even more dangerous to open a port on your database server than it is to open it on your web server, afterall your database is what hackers go for most of the time.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The application is a desktop winforms app.  So, the port would have to be open on all client machines where as a the db server would not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask yourself the following question

> Do I **really** want to use the database server to send out email?

It all depends on how many emails you'll be sending and how busy the SQL server is.

If you'll not be sending many emails and you've got a pretty quiet SQL server; go right ahead.

If (like most of us) you're not that lucky, then look elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe the answer is to just choose the path of least resistance.  We actually are lucky in that there are typically less than 100 users per organization and email is relatively light.  Emails are generally sent for certain status changes as some document routing.  I just hate to lose the flexibility and scalability that .net provides.

Comment: Unfortunately we're not so lucky in our organisation.  We've got a website with over 300'000 active members, and a public site that see much more traffic than that.  When you've got that kind of volume, entrusting the sending of all your email to the database server seems like madness.  Its job is to store and retrieve data, where does email fit into that job description? :-S

Comment: It sounds to me like it might be the best option for you, as it will involve less work and will achieve exactly what you want.  You definitely don't want to send emails directly from each of the client machines.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the dialog.  I was hoping there was more downside to using dbmail or a huge benefit for using .net that I hadn't considered.  I guess I will just bow down and acquiesce.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up dedicated mail server, isolate it from network except for certain IPs and only for inbound connections on port 25. I think it is safe enough. Even if you move to SQL server, you will open port 25 and become vulnerable. You (your coulegues) can manage risks instead of hiding them.

Comment: We have a dedicated mail server.  The problem is a corporate policy stating that mass mail must be turned off on client machines.  We can add exclusion rules for our applications but this may entail a lot of work and red tape. Other team members don't feel the benefit out weighs cost.  Implementing db mail would be easy and would require no letters written or forms filled out.

Answer (score 1):

They are both SMTP solutions using port 25.

You'll have the same issue most likely, it depends on where the scanner is checking/blocking

Comment: Yes, but the change would only need to be made on a single machine and not every client box.

Comment: @LoboFan use dedicated mail server

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts would be to redesign this aspect of the system so that email requests are queued in a database table, and a single machine processes them.

Benefits:

- you don't have to tie up resources on your SQL Server processing volumes of email
- you don't have to go through the paperwork / exclusion sets for all client machines, just the one that's actually going to do the work.

Downsides:

- more work for your developers!

Comment: I like this.  I think it's a perfect solution except for the fact that we would have to have at least one competent person at our remote sites to ensure the service is set up and running.  Unfortunately we don't and I can see the service not coming up after a patch reboot and then email being down until we can solve the problem over the phone.  We had similar problems with the old xp_sendmail in the past where the server would be rebooted and the mail service would not be restarted.